# How does an iOS device (iPad or iPhone) receive “push” notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, notifications, apns

An iOS device (iPad or iPhone) receives notifications, even when the device is sleeping. Apple calls these *“push notifications”*.

**How does the device receive these notifications? Are there any periodic (recurring) actions involved? If so, what actions are they and how often do they occur?**

Comment: Apple has a document about this on the developer site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9

Comment: @Mateusz — I had seen this document by Apple. In it I have seen nothing about my question.

Comment: Do you consider this question to be unanswered? If so, please tell me how I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Apple Push Notification Service documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

> Each device establishes an accredited and encrypted IP connection
>   with APNs and receives notifications over this persistent connection.

This means it uses some sort of socket-based persistent connection. It could be its own proprietary protocol, or [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), etc. The "periodic actions" you're asking about are usually implemented in these protocols at the lowest level possible using TCP/IP sockets and [are being *constantly* polled for new data on the socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html). When the data is finished being read off the socket, an event is fired off to go perform some action such as display a notification on the device.

To further explain, the way sockets work is your device makes a connection to a remote server, the remote server pushes data to your device and gets put into the socket's buffer, then your device reads the socket's buffer and does something with the data. The moment the data gets pushed to your device, your device will process it. This is because your device is checking for new data on the socket's buffer *all the time*. It tries to read data, and if it gets data, it sends it off to get processed and then tries to read data again; if it ever doesn't get data, it just tries to read data again - forever. If the connection to the remote server ever gets disconnected, it just tries to connect again until it succeeds.

The code documentation I linked earlier is taken from [Boost's ASIO library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) which is widely used for sockets in C++. It's implementation and usage can be simplified as follows:

```
01 start program
02 try to connect to server by using a socket
03 if not connected to server, goto 02
04 try to read data on socket
05 if data was read, process data
06 goto 03
```

In step `03` above, the device knows when you're offline and won't attempt to connect again until you get back online (the device sends out an event when you connect to the internet, so it will all happen instantly).

When no data was read in step `04` above, it immediately tries to read it again without waiting (assuming you're still connected to the server). It takes a very small amount of processing power to repeatedly try to read data on the socket, so there's no need to worry about battery or wasted resources (see [@malhal's answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263666/18387) for a better explanation on this and also how it works when the device is sleeping).

Comment: Thank you Andrew. So there is a persistent connection. But what happens when the iDevice has no Internet connection, and when he gets back an Internet connection?

Comment: Andrew, I don't understand your part about periodic actions. Would you be kind kind enough to rephrase or precise?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco I updated my answer and explained how sockets work and how the device tries to reconnect to the server if the connection is lost.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Is my answer clear enough now?

Comment: Thank you Andrew. The algorithm is nice and clear. But, for trying to connect, when off-line, is there a waiting before retrying to connect? If so, how much time? Same questions for trying to read data on the socket when there is no data to read (that is most of the time).

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco The device knows when you're offline and won't connect until you get back online. The device sends out an event when you connect to the internet, so it will all happen instantly. When there is no data to read, it immediately tries to read it again without waiting. It takes a very small amount of processing power to keep reading repeatedly like that, so it doesn't kill your battery or waste resources.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. That is very clear. That is interesting. You may write that in your answer.

Comment: I have added that information to my answer. Do you consider it to be complete now?

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Regarding your last paragraph in the answer now, I am puzzled by the “step `05`”. I would rather link that to the task `04`. Regarding “to keep reading repeatedly like that”, is this correct, or do you mean “to keep trying to read repeatedly like that”?

Comment: Seriously, this is the correct answer and much better explained than the information I found through other sources. @Nicolas, be mindful of chameleon questions.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco I reworded the last paragraph to make it clearer and changed the reference to from step `04` to step `05`. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco If there's no further clarification I need to make, could you please mark this as the correct answer? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't how it works, when the device is asleep the CPU is asleep so it cannot process anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the device CPU is asleep but the cellular modem has another CPU called the baseband processor which keeps running, it monitors for incoming packets that match a certain filter and then wake up the CPU using an interrupt and allows it to process the incoming data. This is trick taken from Microsoft's Pocket PC direct-push, which was an improvement upon Blackberry's implementation that required telco-side BB infrastructure.

Comment: I did not know this! Thanks! So it's similar to what I described, except for it's the baseband processor that's doing the bulk of the work and not the regular CPU? What I was describing in my answer was just more of how socket polling in general works since that's what I understood was being asked (mainly about push notifications in general and that the sleeping part was just auxiliary information).